# Condionally Filtering Dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`:

| Store | Date | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 44725 | B | mango |
| 1 | 44725 | A | Yes |
| 1 | 44725 | E | Yes |
| 1 | 44725 | F | mango |
| 1 | 44625 | G | No |
| 2 | 44625 | A | Yes |
| 2 | 44625 | B |  |
| 2 | 44625 | C | Yes |
| 2 | 44625 | D | apple |
| 2 | 44725 | A | No |
| 3 | 44725 | A | Yes |
| 3 | 44725 | C | Yes |
| 3 | 44725 | D | strawberry |
| 4 | 44726 | C | Yes |
| 4 | 44726 | A | Yes |

A,E,G,C are Questions and B,F,H,D are sub questions under `Question` *respectively*.
For a `store` for a `Date`, If the Question is answered `Yes`,I want to check if follow up /sub questions are present for their Questions, If not I want to get the store,Date,Question pairs as a pandas dataframe.
For example:

For `store` 2,`Date` 44625 `Question` B is null/blank,need this in a separate dataframe like `null_df`:

| Store | Date | Question |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 44625 | B |

For `store` 3,`Date` 44725,`Question` A does not have the sub question so want this in a separate dataframe `df_check`:

| Store | Date | Question |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 44725 | A |
| 4 | 44726 | C |
| 4 | 44726 | A |

For `store` 1 for `Date` 44725 All the questions have sub questions and answers.
How do I get the above 2 dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', header=0)

aaa = {'A': 'B', 'E': 'F', 'G': 'H', 'C': 'D'}


null_df = pd.DataFrame()
df_check = pd.DataFrame()


def my_func(x):
    ind = x[x['Answer'] == 'Yes'].index
    if len(ind) > 0:
        bbb = np.array([[aaa[x.loc[i, 'Question']], x.loc[i, 'Question']] for i in ind])

        fff = x[x['Question'].isin(bbb[:, 0])]
        nu = fff[pd.isnull(fff['Answer'])]
        if len(nu) > 0:
            global null_df
            null_df = pd.concat([null_df, nu[['Store', 'Date', 'Question']]], ignore_index=True)

        check_ind = np.in1d(bbb[:, 0], x['Question'])
        check_ans = bbb[~ check_ind][:, 1]
        check = x[x['Question'].isin(check_ans)]
        if len(check) > 0:
            global df_check
            df_check = pd.concat([df_check, check[['Store', 'Date', 'Question']]], ignore_index=True)


df.groupby(['Store', 'Date']).apply(my_func)

print(null_df)
print(df_check)
```

Output

```
   Store   Date Question
0      2  44625        B


   Store   Date Question
0      3  44725        A
1      4  44726        C
2      4  44726        A
```

A dictionary `aaa` is created in which the keys are `questions`, and the values are `sub-questions`. To find out which sub-question corresponds to the question.

The dataframe is grouped by the 'Store', 'Date' columns. Next, `apply` with a custom function(`my_func`).
Rows where `x['Answer'] == 'Yes'` are selected to get `indexes`. If there are indexes, then we fall under the condition.

The `bbb` list is a nested list with sub-questions on the `left` and questions on the `right` that are selected by indexes where there are 'Yes' questions.

**null_df**:
The `fff` list gets subquestions. With the [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) function, which returns a boolean mask. In nu we get rows where Answer is NaN.

**df_check**:
`check_ind` uses [np.in1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to check if the selected sub-questions match the real ones. check_ind gets a boolean mask with `True` sub-questions present. `check_ans` get a list of questions without sub-questions(apply `tilde ~` reversing the condition). `check` we select lines with the necessary questions using `isin` in which the list of questions is substituted.

[pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) is used to connect both dataframes.

If something is not clear, you can `print` the data of each line of code and see the result.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. Very nice attempt. There is one edge case which it does not handle for questions where more than 2 do not have subs that is not coming up  in `df_check`. could we continue on chat?

Comment: Yes. Add rows to the dataframe to make this happen. To make it easier to understand what you mean.

Comment: @Scope with updated data,  get the expected output like yours (updated it). What's wrong?

Comment: Thanks it works. If you think this was a challenging question pls upvote the question

Comment: I tried the same using pandas but I was stuck and ended up with wrong records, maybe we can have a chat on why my approach didnt work on chat

Comment: Yes, let's talk. But how to get into the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250312/discussion-between-inquirer-and-scope).